# Angular Js push to array from dynamic ng-repeat directive to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need a big favor. I have this ng-repeat directive

```
appTitan.directive('questionsAnswers', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/js/directives/questionsAnswers.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            questions: '=',
            chosenAnswersArr: '='
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.chosenAnswers = function(selection) {
                scope.chosenAnswersArr.push(selection);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

And this is used accordingly in the template

```
<div class="question-answers__item__wrapper">
    <div class="question-answers__item__question">
        <h3>{{ questions.questionName }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="question-answers__item__answers">
        <ul class="row">
            <li class="col-sm-6" data-answer-item-id="{{questions.answerOne.isCorrect}}" ng-click="chosenAnswers(questions.answerOne.isCorrect)">
                <p>{{questions.answerOne.value}}</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-6" data-answer-item-id="{{questions.answerTwo.isCorrect}}" ng-click="chosenAnswers(questions.answerTwo.isCorrect)">
                <p>{{questions.answerTwo.value}}</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-6" data-answer-item-id="{{questions.answerThree.isCorrect}}" ng-click="chosenAnswers(questions.answerThree.isCorrect)">
                <p>{{questions.answerThree.value}}</p>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-6" data-answer-item-id="{{questions.answerFour.isCorrect}}" ng-click="chosenAnswers(questions.answerFour.isCorrect)">
                <p>{{questions.answerFour.value}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and added in HTML like this

```
<li class="question-answers__item" ng-repeat="questions in quizData.questionAndAnswers" elem-height>
    <questions-answers questions="questions" chosenAnswersArr="chosenAnswersArr"></questions-answers>
</li>
```

I have this chosenAnswer ng-click function in my template.

Here's my controller

```
appTitan.controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    'use strict';

    //Generate scores
    $scope.chosenAnswersArr = [];

}]);
```

I am unable to push data from directive to the controller. What is that I have to do to make it work. 
The error I'm getting is

```
angular-1.4.8.min.js:107 TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

I did try adding the controller property(MainController) to the directive but it was breaking the data. Please note that the data is pulled using the same controller using $http.get(I didn't add that line here). I am mentioning this because to let you know that the data is dynamic.

How can I push a data from my directive to the controller?

Comment: Try to console.log `chosenAnswersArr`, what do you have, a string?

Comment: Please a fiddle so it's easier to debug. Also, is there a reason you're using 1.4.8 and not 1.5 + ?

Comment: You probably did a TYPO when passing the binding `chosenAnswersArr="chosenAnswersArr"`. It should be `chosen-answers-arr="chosenAnswersArr"`.

Comment: @nicooga That solves the issue. Thanks a lot